# MX Linux: Grub boot taking way long time

Tags: boot, grub, external-hdd, load, mx-linux

I noticed that GRUB gets stuck and tries to load attached external usb hard drive instead of the internal HDD. If I remove external HDD during boot then it loads immediately. Is there a way I can stop GRUB to look at attached external HDD, atleast until it's loaded linux completely. Attached external HDD has media files & is not bootable but it has few tera bytes of data. I use the machine as plex server & need the external HDD attached if system is rebooted.

In the GRUB logs I see it gets stuck at this point -

```
Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
Starting hotplugevents dispatcher: systemd-udevd.
Synthesizing the initial hotplus events (subsystems)... done.
Synthesizing the initial hotplug events (devices)...done.
Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...done.
```

Any suggestions? Linux version Is MX-21_x64, kernel 5.10.0-11

Comment: could you attach your grub config?

Comment: @mashuptwice here's /boot/grub/grub.conf: https://easyupload.io/suxtqd

Comment: Update:
Turns out it was the disk check at every startup when the drive was mounted. I changed the entry in /etc/fstab to disable the check (last field changed to 0) and it was fine.

Comment: You might want to add your comment as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the disk check at every startup when the drive was mounted. I changed the entry in /etc/fstab to disable the check (last field changed to 0) and it was fine.